# Java- For loop - call another function every certain seconds

Tags: java

So I have a for loop iterating through a large list (so taking long time). So I want it to call `helper.clear()`(session) every 200 second (when I am running the for loop). how should I do it?

I see timer and thread.sleep() in other similar post, and not sure which is better, or if there's better answer for my case.

It would be something similar to:

```
for(int a : aList) {
    //this for loop takes ~ 10 min

    //call session.clear() every 200 second when we are running the for loop
}
```

Comment: and what is helper ?

Comment: It's and helper class and its method

Comment: Best explanation ever, thanks.
Really ? Can't you be more precise ?

Comment: Most efficient would be calling helper.clear() every N iterations. Other option would be to call it every 200 seconds, if that's what you really want. Pick either. If you are unsure how, look up `if` statement...

Comment: I don't want to do every N iterations, want to do it every certain seconds

Comment: You can start another thread if the loop takes so long. In that thread, just call the function after sleeping for 200 seconds.

Comment: @clinomaniac how to do it?

Comment: @KKlalala Look at ice1000's answer.

Comment: Pseudocode `if (timestamp + 200 seconds < current time) { session.clear(); timestamp = current time; }`

Comment: Maybe it's also a good idea to improve the application architecture and/or data model.  I don't know the details but I think there could be a lot improved. Think on async programming, parallelism, faster queries, ...

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep()` is poorly designed and make the code hard to read, `java.util.Timer` is better.

Your code will be something like:

```
Timer timer = new java.util.Timer(true);
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        session.clear();
    }
};

timer.schedule(task, 200L);
```

You can simplify your code step by step.

#### step 0

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        session.clear();
    }
};
new Timer(true).schedule(task, 200L);
```

#### step 1

```
TimerTask task = session::clear;
new Timer(true).schedule(task, 200L);
```

#### step 2

```
new Timer(true).schedule(session::clear, 200L);
```

Comment: Should I just make the class and then call `timer.schedule(task, delay) ` at the beginning of the for loop?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can test the code above yourself, it works for me

Comment: @Kayaman Run `Thread.sleep()` like a minute, and observe your task manager, and you know.

Comment: There's no overload of `sleep()` that doesn't take an argument, and if I call `Thread.sleep(60000);` my task manager isn't going to do anything. So again, what does "Thread.sleep() takes high CPU usage" mean?

Comment: In this answer, you might want to mention something about thread safety... It sounds like session might be used in the loop too, and in that case adding threads will open a can of synchronization worms.

Comment: But sleeping isn't CPU intense. A spinlock like `while(true);` is. Using sleep isn't recommended because of the CPU usage, but the general poor design that usually means (i.e. you mimicing what `Timer` already does).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = () -> {helper.clear(); };
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000 * 200);
```

A neat way to use it would be creating a method:

```
public void setRecurrentTask(Runnable runnable, long delay, long interval) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = () -> {runnable.run(); };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, interval);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
setRecurrentTask(someClass::someMethodThatRunsEvery200Seconds, 0, 1000 * 200);
```

Comment: In this answer, you might want to mention something about thread safety... It sounds like session might be used in the loop too, and in that case adding threads will open a can of synchronization worms.